# Reading an XML file with an unkown format in C

Tags: c, xml-parsing

How do I read from an XML file with an unkown format, for example a file can be of the format:

```
<data1>int1</data1>
<data2>int2</data2>
<data3>int3</data3>
<data4>int4</data4>
```

OR

```
<data1>int1</data1>
<data4>int4</data4>
```

OR

```
<data1>int1</data1>
<data2>int2</data2>
<data3>int3</data3>
<data4>int4</data4>
<data5>int5</data5>
```

In the second case I am to assume int2 and int3 are to be assigned default values. I thought of one way to solve this problem but it came out messy and spaghetti like.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) None of those is a complete XML document. There needs to be a single root element.

(2) If you don't insist on restricting the number and order of their of instances, it's easy to declare in a DTD that element content can be a mix of other elements, using the '|' operator. (See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-element-content)

(3) If you want to constrain those more tightly, then yes, DTDs can require spelling out all the combinations. Switching to validating against [XML Schemas](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema) is one obvious solution; DTDs are pretty much considered obsolete anyway since they aren't compatible with XML Namespaces (which have become a basic part of XML processing).

(4) If you insist on sticking with DTDs, and can't accept unconstrained order/count, and don't want to spell out all the possible sequences... consider doing some of that checking and/or applying of default values in your application code rather than in the DTD.